# Error on char array declaration in GCC 3.3.4

Tags: c++, c, gcc, gcc-warning

```
int main () {

   char b[100];
   for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++ )
       scanf ("%c%*c", b[i]);
}
```

but am getting the error 'Format arguemnt is not a pointer'

How can i declare an array to get all values form the user?

**EDIT :**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


int p[100], b, bc;
char bb[100];

int main () {


        printf("Enter Count : ");
        scanf ("%d", &bc);
        for (b = 1; b <= bc; b++ ) {
            printf("Enter a char and integer: ");
            scanf ("%c%*c %d", &bb[b-1], &p[b-1]);
            printf ("\n Your Entries =>  %c,  %d", bb[b-1], p[b-1]);
        }


    return 0;
}
```

This is my source code.

Comment: That is not how you write a for-loop in C or C++.

Comment: :) just to showcase how, nothing else.. :)

Comment: for what reason you guys closing this?

Comment: Your declaration is ok. Try `char b[100]; fgets(b, sizeof b, stdin);` ... and post real compilable (or very nearly compilable) code.

Comment: Not quite sure why this being so heavily downvoted/voted-to-close...

Comment: After the edit: @coderex: you can't use `b` as `int` **and** `char[]` simultaneously. Change one of the names and alter the code accordingly.

Comment: @pmg Sorry That was a miskte while copying from orginal source, i changed as bb. but not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <cstdio>
```

Apparently, you're coding in C++

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Oh! Wait. It is C after all.
**@coderex**: make up your mind what language you're using

```
using namespace std;
```

Oh! It is C++. **My answer does not consider the C++ specifics which I don't know.**

```
int p[100], b, bc;
char bb[100];
```

If you can avoid using global variables, your code will be easier to deal with.

```
int main () {


        printf("Enter Count : ");
        scanf ("%d", &bc);
        for (b = 1; b <= bc; b++ ) {
```

The idiomatic way is `for (b = 0; b < bc; b++)`. Using the idiomatic way, you won't need to subtract 1 inside the loop to access the array indexes.

```
            printf("Enter a char and integer: ");
            // scanf ("%c%*c %d", &bb[b-1], &p[b-1]);
```

`scanf()` is notoriously difficult to use correctly.
Anyway the `"%d"` conversion specifier already discards whitespace so you can remove the strange stuff; also there's an ENTER pending from the last `scanf` call. Using a space in the format string gets rid of it.

```
            scanf (" %c%d", &bb[b-1], &p[b-1]);
            printf ("\n Your Entries =>  %c,  %d", bb[b-1], p[b-1]);
        }


    return 0;
}
```

**Have fun!**

Comment: after 8 year gap I'm using C/C++. :)

Comment: I recommend you stick with one of `C` or `C++` (or `C#`, or `D`, ...). Don't try to write a multi-language source file. LOL

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
scanf("%c", &b[i]);
```

`scanf()` needs to know the *address* of the variable, so that it can modify it.

Comment: no there is no error now, but when i tried to print its not showing

Comment: I need "%c%*c" this because I want to read an integer after each char, other wise the newline entry will break the execution

Comment: @coderex: Yes, you may need to modify this for your exact requirements.  My code snippet above was to demonstrate the need to provide an *address*.

Comment: @coderex: `printf("%c\n", b[i]);`.

Comment: yes, but nothing is printing :(

Comment: @coderex: I cannot help you unless you provide some *actual* code.

Comment: I willupdate the latest code, its working in one section and not in another section

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth please check my EDIT

Answer (score 0):

Error was, its reading the "enter key" as newline char after an integer value enter.

to avoid this I used %*c `scanf ("%c%*c %d%*c", &bb[b-1], &p[b-1]);`

thank you everybody.

Comment: See my answer ... but `scanf(" %c%d", &bb[b - 1], &p[b - 1]);` "works" and is easier on the eyes and brain.